# Why do I receive an angular-modal-service error when passing data to the modal controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am using [angular-modal-service](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service) to show modal in my [yeoman generated angular application](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular). I'm following the documentation but got this error when passing data through `inputs` argument.

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userProvider <- user <-
>   targetModalCtrl

This is the function on controller where the modal is triggered

```
'use strict';

angular.module('webClientApp')
  .controller('LogCreateCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $log, $http, config, ModalService, $route) {

  /*-- OTHER FUNCTIONS --*/     

  // record time in
  $scope.recordTimeIn = function() { 
    // show target modal
    ModalService.showModal({
      templateUrl: "views/targetModal.html",
      controller: "targetModalCtrl",
      inputs: {
        user: $scope.user.id
      }
    }).then(function(modal) {
      modal.element.modal();
      modal.close.then(function(result) {
        $log.debug(result);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

and this is the modal controller :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('webClientApp')
  .controller('targetModalCtrl', ['$scope', 'user', function($scope, user) {
    $log.debug(user);
}]);
```

The modal is showing fine if I'm not using the `inputs` arguments in `LogCreateCtrl` and remove the `user` in `targetModalCtrl`.

Comment: what is user here. factory or service ?

Comment: Can you please share a plunker for the same?

Comment: @BharatBhushan it is the data from controller where modal is triggered.

Comment: @nikhil.agw okay, I'll prepare it first

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that `angular-modal-service` but I see two potential problems...

1. I'm not sure whether the modal service is robust enough to handle injection through the array notation ([the docs](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service#usage) aren't clear on this)
2. I don't see `$log` among the controller's parameters

You might try changing your controller to the following...

```
angular.module('webClientApp')
  .controller('targetModalCtrl', function($scope, $log, user) {
    $log.debug(user);
});
```

Comment: Oh yes thanks I forget to include the $log, but I tried it but the problem still persist. In this [sample](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service/blob/master/samples/complex/complexcontroller.js), it is using array injection. Any clue why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue that case cause the problem.

In inputs the value of user is $scope.user.id, now in controller, i am not able to see, user.id set anywhere in scope, which will mean undefined value assigned to user.

Modal service removes the undefined values and hence, is not able to inject user.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't put the full code. The `$scope.user.id` has been declared with a value before. However, even if I change the input value from `$scope.user.id` to random string (ex: 'test'), it still gives the error.